# Regex - How to match single character while excluding two in a row?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the property names ("SUP NR", "QUANTITY", "MOD/REF") in the following example using regular expressions:

> SUP NR: K16518-1, QUANTITY: 2 PIECES// MOD/REF: 16-1P1-0612

Note:

- Property names are always followed by a ':' character
- Properties can consist of multiple words, either separated by spaces ("SUP NR") or by / ("MOD/REF")
- There is a space character at the beginning (before "SUP NR")

I tried to do so using the following regular expression:

```
(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z\s/]+:
```

The (?<=\s) negative look-behind I use, because there is always a 'space' before a property name.

It would work, if it wasn't for the double '//' characters, which of course match the '/' char in the character set. Is there a way to include only single '/' chars into the character set while excluding double '//' characters? (Maybe there is also a more elegant approach to this?)

EDIT:
Note, properties might also consist of more than two words. Also, the chosen property names are just examples, it should also work for different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\s([a-zA-Z]+(?:[/\s][a-zA-Z]+)*):
```

It looks for a word preceded by a space, followed by optional groups of a separator (space or `/`) and another word, followed by a `:`. For your data group 1 is `SUP NR`, `QUANTITY` and `MOD/REF`.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/10VN6x/2)

With python, you would use this regex like this:

```
import re
string = " SUP NR: K16518-1, QUANTITY: 2 PIECES// MOD/REF: 16-1P1-0612"
regex = re.compile('\s([a-zA-Z]+(?:[/\s][a-zA-Z]+)*):')
print regex.findall(string)
```

Output:

```
['SUP NR', 'QUANTITY', 'MOD/REF']
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/UDHD23547)

Comment: This indeed works on regex101, but when I try it in sublime or in python (re package) it won't work.. what might be the reason for that?

Comment: @nkaenzig I've added python code that shows the regex working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, it works on the example in the post. But when I run it on a larger set of data, it freezes (happens in sublime & python)

Comment: @nkaenzig Can you figure out what data it is freezing on?

Comment: Yes sure, below an example where it freezes, at least in python and sublime. (note in this example there is not much that matches the regex). I noticed, that the regex works well for short examples like the one I posted originally. But the longer the sample gets, the slower, until at some point it freezes.
https://regex101.com/r/AmCm55/1

Comment: @nkaenzig I've updated the regex to avoid possible catastrophic backtracking which was causing the freezing problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the look behind. You can be more specific too.

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+([ /][a-zA-Z]+)*(?=:)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/IXNqcYE1Zb).

---

btw, your look behind is not a *negative* look behind, it's a *positive* one - a negative look behind uses syntax `(?<!...)`

Comment: This only works for property names that consist of exactly two words. It should also work for properties consisting of more words.

Comment: @nkaenzig fixed (basically changed `?` to `*`)